# How to use elasticsearch query with searchUsers function in Kuzzle?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kuzzle

i set a property called `type` in some users with the kuzzle console, now i want to search for user who have the `type` set to `user` so i use a query for searching user.
Here is my code:

```
const resultUsers = await kuzzle.security.searchUsers({
  query: {
    term: {
      type: "user"
    }
  }
})
console.log(resultUsers)
```

I also tried with this query too:

```
query: {
  term: {
    "content.type": "user"
  }
}
```

and this one:

```
query: {
  term: {
    "_source.type": "user"
  }
}
```

But the function always return 0 users. Can someone explain me why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only search for properties that have been [properly indexed](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/main-concepts/data-storage/#collection-mappings).

You can check the mappings of the internal users collection with the [security:getUserMapping](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/api/controllers/security/get-user-mapping/) API action or with the Admin Console.

Then you need to modify the mappings to include your new property:

```
  {
    "properties": {
      "type": { "keyword" }
    }
  }
```

For this, you can use the [security:updateUserMapping](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/api/controllers/security/update-user-mapping/) API action or again, the Admin Console.